# Load the build.json file of the specific project automatically without hardcoding

Tags: groovy, spock

I am running a test case and I want the code to automatically load the respective .json file .

Right now I am hardcoding the file ,but I want it loaded when the respective test class runs ,so looking to make it generic.

````
  def setupSpec() {
  config = (Map) new 
     JsonSlurper().parse(getClass().getResourceAsStream("wps.build.json"))
    config.build = "Wps build ${new Date()}"
    caps = bsLocal.defaultCaps
    caps.setCapability("build", config.build)
    caps.setCapability("browserstack.console", "info")
    attempts = config.environments.size()
  }```
````

This is the structure 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpXa0.jpg

Comment: load it by class name for example  `WPS.class` -> `wps.json`. what's the problem?

Comment: if I run the other test case ,how do I get the class name for the running test case??

Comment: `this.getClass().getName()`

Comment: yeah this is fine , but the setupspec as per spock framework runs before the first method . So this setupspec is on an other class . So while it runs I need to get the class name . this.getClass().getName() would return the class name of the setupspec() methods class . what I need is the the test cases class name ,here so I  could interpolate and append the name rather than hardcode. You get it bro ?